# how to use Net Reactor Direct rewrite original file?

Tags: c#, net-reactor

when I use Net Reactor encrypt my project ,it will create xxxx_secure folder, But i hope Direct rewrite original file,how to do ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the target file and make it the same as the input file.

Using the command line it looks like this:

```
dotnet_reactor.exe -file "xyz.dll" -targetfile "xyz.dll"
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it in .net Reactor tool?
In the tools setting it is mentioned as <AssemblyLocation>\<AssemblyName>_Secure\<AssemblyFileName>

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite the original file you need to use <AssemblyLocation>\<AssemblyFileName> or alternatively the full path for the "Target File" option.

However, it is recommended to use <AssemblyLocation>\<AssemblyFileName> as it doesn't break paths if you move the file.